# Программно привязать/указать/изменить Script в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

### **КАК привязать СКРИПТ к ОБЪЕКТУ на сцене ПРОГРАММНО?**

Довольно недавно начал изучать Unity. Всё шло довольно ровно и хорошо, пока не случилось это. Я решил сделать так: (приведена аналогия, чтобы проще было понять):

1) Создаю кубик

2) Делаю клон этого кубика по клику кнопки

3) Указать для этого клона другой скрипт (когда создается клон, то скрипт не дублируется)

Запоролся на 3-ем шаге ¯_(ツ)_/¯

1) Куб уже есть на сцене
2) Дублирую с помощью `Instantiate(myCube);` 
3) Кубик от которого создаются копии просто двигается по сцене (WASD), а кубики, которые дублируются меняют цвет/хаотично двигаются/увеличиваются
4) Для каждого созданого кубика действие, которое он будет выполнять задается случайно

```
GameObject cube;
...
void createCloneCube(){
    GameObject clone;
    clone = Instantitate(cube) as GameObject;
    clone.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
    //Тут должен быть скрипт добавления компонета Script к clone
}
```

Comment: Почему скрипт не дублируется? Вполне себе должен быть полной копией. Каким образом клонируешь? Какого вида скрипты? Они совсем разную логику задают или имеют одинаковую логику (типа KnifeWeapon, GunWeapon, TomatoAttack) ? Что эти кубики в целом делают и значат?

Comment: сначала надо привязывать скрипт, а потом делать пребаф. В этом случае всё должно продублироваться

Comment: Ну как обычно, сделают в скрипте ссылку на GameObject/Transform( та любой ссылочный объект), а при клонировании, скрипт клонируется, но ссылка остается на тот самый GameObject/Transform, а потом спамят на форумах, что "скрипт не клонируется", "Unity сломалась". Надо уметь клонировать GameObject со сцены, с префабом такой проблемы нет.

Comment: 1) Куб уже есть на сцене 2) Дублирую с помощью Instantiate(myCube); 3) Кубик от которого создаются копии просто двигается по сцене (WASD), а кубики, которые дублируются меняют цвет/хаотично двигаются/увеличиваются 4) Для каждого созданого кубика действие, которое он будет выполнять задается случайно

Comment: Изменить надо это: http://prntscr.com/g94v7k

Comment: Покажи код и покажи конкретно что на что ты хочешь поменять....редактируй вопрос и добавляй всё более подробное описание туда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameObject cube;
...
void createCloneCube(){
    GameObject clone = Instantitate(cube) as GameObject;
    clone.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
    "Компонент" addComp=clone.AddComponent<"Компонент">();
}
```

Есть 4 способа прикрепить скрипт(он же компонент) к объекту:

1). кнопочка Add Component в редакторе объекта

2). взять скрипт и перетащить на объект

3). в другом скрипте написать [RequireComponent(typeof("Компонент"))]

4). последний я выше написал.

Comment: Мне нужно к клону прикрепить другой скрипт

Comment: @Александр, а это что? Сделай префаб, пустой куб без скрипта, после клонирования добавляйте скрипт нужный и при этом не надо удалять предыдущий.

Comment: Как его (скрипт) добавить программно?

Comment: @Александр "Компонент" addComp=clone.AddComponent<"Компонент">();

Comment: Я не про то. Как прикрепить сам скрипт из Assets? Сам C# скрипт. Как на картинке:https://prnt.sc/g94v7k

Comment: Есть 4 способа прикрепить скрипт к объекту, кнопочка Add Component в редакторе объекта, взять скрипт и перетащить на объект, в другом скрипте написать [RequireComponent(typeof("Компонент"))]  и последний я выше написал.

Comment: @Александр Компонент это и есть скрипт

Comment: Спасибо, дошло. Я считал, что есть компонент "Script", где в свойствах нужно указать сам скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Любой созданный скрипт автоматически становится компонентом.[image: В поиске компонентов скрипт отображается вместе с другими (компонентами)]

Чтобы добавить скрипт программно нужно:

1. Создать сам скрипт
2. Указать в коде, где создается клон/префаб:

   clone.AddComonent< CubeScript >();